# Angular ng-change call to a Component Class function not triggering

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs-ng-change

I am trying to implement a live search box in angular using ng-change, but the function I am passing it doesn't seem to be triggering. The code is as follows

HTML

```html
<input type="text" 
  [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" 
  ng-change="updateSearch()"
  name="firstname" 
  placeholder="Search Courses, Challenges, Datasets...">
```

Javascript

```
export class SearchbarComponent implements OnInit {

  results = RESULTS;
  filteredResults: SearchResult[];

  searchTerm: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredResults = this.results.slice();
  }

  updateSearch():void {
    console.log("fish");
    this.filteredResults = [];

     this.results.forEach(function(element) {
       if (element.startsWith(this.searchTerm)) {
         this.filteredResults.append(element);
       }
     });

  }
updateSearch():void {
        console.log("fish");
        this.filteredResults = [];

         this.results.forEach(function(element) {
           if (element.startsWith(this.searchTerm)) {
             this.filteredResults.append(element);
           }
         });

      }
}
```

So I put the console log in there to see if it was triggering, not getting anything.

Comment: `ng-change` is for use with Angular 1.x. See [here](https://angular.io/guide/forms#track-control-state-and-validity-with-ngmodel) for examples on how to track state with Angular now.

Comment: Use `(ngModelChange)` instead of `ng-change`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ng-change` does not exist in Angular 2+ as that is Angular 1.x syntax. The syntax for [Event Binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#event-binding---event-) looks like `(change)`, `(input)`, and `(click)` to name a few:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="someVar" (input)="someHandler($event)" />
```

You'd need to instead use event binding `(input)` to track input/change events for `<input />` of type `text`:

```
<input type="text" 
    [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" 
    (input)="updateSearch()"
    name="firstname" 
    placeholder="Search Courses, Challenges, Datasets..." />
```

You can additionally pass `$event` to the function in the template to gain access to the HTML [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) for `value`, `target`, or anything else you may need.

```
<input (input)="updateSearch($event)" />
```

Here is a simple [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-64mjya) of `(input)` event binding in action, logging the a passed `$event` on each input/change that occurs.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: I ended up using ngModelChange put thanks for the information